# require at least one field in a group on Form Assembly for Salesforce integration

Tags: forms, salesforce, connector

Requirements:

- 1-3 email addresses
- types for those email addresses (corresponding with Salesforce's Personal, Work, and Alternate)
- one of those email addresses to be the preferred/primary

Non-ideal solutions:

- Create one field asking for type for each email field.  Problems: difficult to validate that the same type isn't being selected for multiple addresses.  Vague email fields require formula mapping in Salesforce connector instead of simple field to field mapping.
- Create one field per email type + checkbox field next to each asking if it's their preferred email.  Problems: difficult to validate that more than one checkbox isn't being checked.  Don't want to make any of them required fields but want at least one to be populated.

I'm building this form for users without html coding experience and need a solution that will be easy to replicate.  I figured out one solution and will post it in the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make five new fields in the form:

1. Radio or Picklist: "Preferred Email Address Type". Options: Personal, Work,
   Alternate. Required field.
2. Text: "Personal Email"

   - Validation: Expected Input Format: Email.
   - Calculations: This is a variable. Name: "personalemail"
3. Text: "Work Email"

   - Validation: Expected Input Format: Email.
   - Calculations: This is a variable. Name: "workemail"
4. Text: "Alternate Email"

   - Validation: Expected Input Format: Email.
   - Calculations: This is a variable. Name: "alternateemail"
5. Text: "Email Check"

   - Validation: Expected Input Format: Custom... Validate with a Regular Expression: /[^0]+/
   - Calculations: This is a calculated field. Formula: personalemail+workemail+alternateemail

How this works:
When all three email fields are blank, the Email Check field displays 0.  The regular expression returns an error if the field exactly = 0.  None of the 3 email fields should be required on the form itself, allowing some to be left blank but not allowing all of them to be left blank.

Bonus: If you want to hide the Email Check field, you can't make it a hidden field and keep the validation.  Create a new section, put the field in the section, and hide the section and the field won't be visible on the form but will still validate appropriately.